# Does wifi availbility affect internet speed on other computers?

Tags: wireless-networking

We have wifi availability at our office.  We are being told that when wifi is not being used, even the fact that it is available will slow down internet usage on our office computers.
They say that smart phones and tablets will still search for the wifi connection even when they do not have the password to actually use it and that that will slow down the internet on our office computers.
Is this true?

Comment: I'd say no. It might be broadcasting an SSID, but that shouldn't bog down your internet speed.

Comment: The wifi broadcasting its SSID will not slow down your wired connections. However a large amount of wireless browsing could theoretically have an effect on your wired speeds.

Comment: We know nothing about your setup and they (presumably) are experts. If they're right, then it sounds like you have a particularly crappy WiFi setup and should probably consider investing $100 or so in upgrading it.

Answer (score -1):

Is the WiFi router and ISP router/modem the same device?

If so then your speeds can be bogged down in theory by the fact that CPU cycles will be wasted on WiFi shenanigans when it really needs to be dedicated to processing wired traffic.

To avoid this you should have the following setup:

- Wall to ISP router, disable WiFi
- ISP router to switch
- Switch to dedicated WiFi router
- Switch to the rest of the wired lines (office computers)

Comment: Interesting theory and certainly has logic to it.  But any references or experiences to document that this theory is fact?